# Reformat string containing date with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace, str-replace

I have the following string which I ultimately need to have in the format of mm/yy

```
    var expDate = 2016-03;
    var formatExp = expDate.replace(/-/g , "/");
```

This gets me to 2016/03, but how can i get to 03/16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution without regex:

```js
var expDate = '2016-03';
var formatExp = expDate.split('-').reverse().join('/');
//result is 03/2016
alert('result: ' + formatExp);

var formatExpShort = expDate.substring(2).split('-').reverse().join('/');
//result is 03/16
alert('result short: ' + formatExpShort);
```

Comment: Thanks and that's super close but it does not drop the first two digits of the year?

Comment: You the man!  Thanks a ton. I'll mark as resolved in just a min

Answer (score 1):

With a RegExp :

`'2016-03'.replace(/^\d{2}(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/, '$1/$2')`

Comment: this got a vote from me, i love regex but im too slow for that kind of solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use RegExp?

Why not creating a simple function that splits the exp Date and returns it the way you want it?

```
function parseDate(expDate){

     var dateArray = expDate.split('-')
     return dateArray[1] + '/' + dateArray[0].substring(2,4)
}
```

The split functions creates an array, the element in position `1` is the month, the element in position `2` is the year, on the latter you apply the substring function which extrapolates the last two digits.