# How to standardize date strings to YYYY.MM.DD format?

Tags: javascript, json, string, date

Inside my JSON there are three different types of date values:

- `D.M.YYYY`
- `DD.M.YYYY`
- `D.MM.YYYY`.

How would you suggest me to standardize this to `YYYY.MM.DD` format? (like 2022.02.02 instead of 2.02.2022 or 02.2.2022 or 2.2.2022)?

Comment: How about storing a unix timestamp instead? Then you don't have to worry about timezone information either.

Comment: Split, pad with zeroes, join.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Comment: Duplicate of [*Reformat string containing date with Javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784911/reformat-string-containing-date-with-javascript)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433313/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
dmy="9.8.2034".split("."); 

result = ("0000" + dmy[2]).slice(-4) +"." 
       + ("00" + dmy[1]).slice(-2) +"." 
       + ("00" + dmy[0]).slice(-2);

// result = "2034.08.09"
```

While this is my general approach, in your case, if you are certain that the D and M fields will definitely always contain at least 1 digit, and the Y field will always be a full 4-digit year, you *could* chop off some of the extra "0"s you are adding.

```
result = dmy[2]+"." 
       + ("0" + dmy[1]).slice(-2) +"." 
       + ("0" + dmy[0]).slice(-2);
```

Personally, however, I would suggest using my more verbose first method above, as it will be easier for you to recognise what your intention was when you are later re-reading your code.

Comment: You can just [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)