# Date(string) shows different date and time using toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, date

I want to turn the string `1822-01-01 00:00:00` into a date by:

```
var d= new Date("1822-01-01 00:00:00");
```

What I expect using `d.toLocaleString()` is `1.1.1822, 00:00:00`, but what I get is `31.12.1821, 23:53:28`.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1kLpfgd/

[Javascript Date string constructing wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774293/javascript-date-string-constructing-wrong-date) explains the wrong date with time zones. I have a different problem, as even minutes and seconds differ from my input. The solution using the `new Date(1822, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` constructor does not work for me, as the result is `31.12.1821, 23:53:28`.

Is it because the year is before 1901? But even 1899 works perfectly fine...

**Update**

For the formatting example custom VS toLocaleString, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1kLpfgd/8/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: parse a string to Date as LOCAL time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908299/javascript-parse-a-string-to-date-as-local-time-zone)

Comment: Month 1 is **February** in JavaScript.

Comment: use `d.toString()` instead of `d.toLocaleString()` because toLocaleString dependent on current time zone.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: @BrahmaDev: As I pointed out, I'd understand if only the hours differed. But time zones don't explain second differences.

Comment: @Pointy: A yes thank you. I updated that part. The time is still different, though.

Comment: @chakri: Huh... that... seems to be the wanted date. Thanks! So it's only formatted horribly wrong... I still have trouble formatting the date the way I want, but your hint tells me the date itself should be correct.

Comment: @Neepsnikeep I realize it now. The change appears in 1911/12. Don't know why.

Comment: Don't use the built-in parser. In Safari, `new Date("1822-01-01 00:00:00")` returns an invalid date. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Also, the format returned by *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, even the related standard (ECMA 402) does not define the format to use for particular languages (it's not actually based on locale at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use some library like [**date-fns**](https://date-fns.org/) , [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) ...
To get the desired you could try like:

```js
var dateString = "1822-01-01 00:00:00";

var d = new Date(dateString);
var formatted = d.getDate() +'.'+
                (d.getMonth()+1) +'.'+
                d.getFullYear() +', '+
                dateString.substr(11);

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: That works and moments.js does exactly what I want, thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/f1kLpfgd/7/

Comment: Please do not suggest using the built-in parser, particularly for non–standard strings. In Safari, `new Date("1822-01-01 00:00:00")` returns an invalid date.

Comment: @Roko: Ah, now I see why you put the month+1 in parentheses. Thanks for solving a problem I haven't run into, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to turn the string 1822-01-01 00:00:00 into a date by:
>
> ```
> var d= new Date("1822-01-01 00:00:00");
> ```
>
> What I expect using d.toLocaleString() is 1.1.1822, 00:00:00, but what I get is 31.12.1821, 23:53:28.

Do not use the built-in parser for non-standard strings as whatever you get is implementation dependent and likely not what you expect in at least some hosts. In Safari, *d* will be an invalid date.

The format returned by *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent and varies between browsers. For me, `new Date().toLocaleString()` returns "9/21/2017, 9:48:49 AM", which is not consistent with the format typically used either in my locality or by users of the language I speak.

If you just want to reformat the string, see [*Reformat string containing date with Javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784911/reformat-string-containing-date-with-javascript).

If you want to know how to parse the string correctly, see [*Why does Date.parse 
give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

If you want to format a Date, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will test with Safari. I will not write my own parser for stuff whole libraries are dedicated to. For the locations I need, toLocaleString gives me the right format (just with wrong numbers). That's why I wanted to use it rather than do some unreadable custom formatting in that line. But as it's the only way I get a correct date string, I do it now.

Comment: @Neepsnikeep—the "wrong numbers" appears to be a bug, most browsers have some for particular times or dates (testing around daylight saving changeover is fraught).